# How to grab variable from an import module

Tags: python

I am trying to get the variable - `clipFileInfo` in which it came from an import module. I run the following code:

```
from Library import libmaya
publishClip = libmaya.ClipPublish()
clip = publishClip.getClip()

print clip.clipFileInfo
```

But it will give me an error saying that `# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clipFileInfo' #`

This is the portion of code that I am deriving from

```
class ClipPublish( lib.ClipPublish ):
    ...
    ...

    def __getclipFileInfo( self ):
        '''
        Return list of dicts to pass through to writeClip function
        '''
        clipFileInfo = []
        for rig in self.rigList.Rigs():
            actor = rig.pop( 'actor', None )
            if actor:
                clipFileInfo = {}
                clipFileInfo['actor'] = actor
                clipFileInfo['rig'] = rig
                clipFileInfo['name'] = self.__unit.get( rig['name'] )
                clipFileInfo.append( clipFileInfo )               
        return clipFileInfo

    def getClip( self ):
        clipFileInfo = self.__getclipFileInfo()
        if clipFileInfo:
            start = self.frameRange.startFrame()
            end = self.frameRange.endFrame()
            clipFile = writeC.writeclip( clipFileInfo, start, end )
            if clipFile == None:
                return None
            return clipFile[0] if self.isSingle() else clipFile
        return []
```

Is this possible to do so in the first place?

Comment: Call `publishClip.__getclipFileInfo()`

Comment: I think this error means clip.clipFileInfo is [] but not a variable with content.

Comment: @ForceBru I am getting the error `# AttributeError: 'ClipPublish' object has no attribute '__getclipFileInfo' #`

Comment: @yan, `__getclipFileInfo` or `__getclipFileInfo()`? With or without braces?

Comment: @ForceBru I actually tried both, with and without `()` and both gave me the same error

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to pull a local variable out of a function. Unless the function returns this local variable, it is not possible.

Instead, as the comment says, you should call `publishClip.__getclipFileInfo()` to get the value of that variable, since that function *does* return it.

To be more explicit, try the following code.

```
from Library import libmaya
publishClip = libmaya.ClipPublish()
info = publishClip.__getclipFileInfo()

print info
```

Comment: Hi merlin2011, as mentioned by ForceBru, when I tried running that, I got `# AttributeError: 'ClipPublish' object has no attribute '__getClipInfo' # `

Comment: @KlausD. Hey, I seems to have omit out the "File".. Ahh.. This is the correct error I am getting `# AttributeError: 'ClipPublish' object has no attribute '__getclipFileInfo' #`

Comment: @yan ...and even more care. (Python is case-sensitive)

Comment: @KlausD. Damn, no idea what is happening to me, argh... But unfortunately, still the same :(

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm sure your answer will work, however it is not working for me, for reasons unknown to me.. Like I have mentioned in the past few comments of mine, while trying to grab the values from `__getclipFileInfo`, I am getting this error - `# AttributeError: 'ClipPublish' object has no attribute '__getclipFileInfo' #`. As such, this doesn't works for me :(

Comment: @yan, One possibility is that the library you are importing is not the library that you think you're importing from. In particular, perhaps you are looking at the source code for a newer version of the library than the one that is installed in your system.